# Как отобразить информацию полученную с помощью сервиса Angular 6

Tags: service, angular5

Получаю с сервера список объектов и мне нужно отобразить их по очереди, а не сразу списком. Делаю простой опросник. Хочу в данный момент, чтобы выводился  первый вопрос после загрузки страницы, но не могу в контроллере вытащить первое значение из **questions** так как надо дождаться подгрузки списка. Как правильно это сделать?

```
вот контроллер: 
questionform.componetn.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Question} from "../question";
import {questionService} from "../question.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questionform',
  templateUrl: './questionform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionform.component.css']
})
export class QuestionformComponent implements OnInit {

  questions: Question[];
  question: string = this.question[0].question;

  constructor(private questionService: QuestionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuestions();
  }

  getQuestions(): void{
    this.questionService.getQuestions().subscribe(questions => this.questions = questions);
  }

}

вот вьюха:
questionform.component.html

<p>{{question}}</p>
<button onClick()="next()">next</button>
```

Comment: Ну так дождитесь, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю у тебя там отпечатка должно быть так question: string = this.questions[0].question; Но суть не в этом сделай так чтобы при получение данных с сервера делай присвоение сразу Например:

```
getQuestions(): void{
    this.questionService.getQuestions().subscribe(questions => {
        this.questions = questions;
        this.question = this.questions[0].question});
}
```

questionform.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="question">
    <p>{{question}}</p>
    <button onClick()="next()">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! не знал что можно сразу делать присвоение так. Это решило мою проблему.